# Get values from GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView that is populated by a service and I have added a link on each line of this grid so that I may take action when that specific row is clicked.  I want to get some of the items in the selected row but even if I add a onSelectedRowChanged event I am not getting that event to fire, just my link.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTransactionHistory" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
    onselectedindexchanging="gvTransactionHistory_SelectedIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("preAuthAmount") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Assign+" OnClick="btnAssign"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my btnAssign click event, which works fine...

```
protected void btnAssign(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Works!");
}
```

I added this to see if I could trigger this event but I am not really changing index so what I need help with is understanding what event I can tie into that will allow me to click my link button, and get the values from THAT row.

```
protected void gvTransactionHistory_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    var amount = gvTransactionHistory.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
    Response.Write(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the `btnAssign` click event handler to get the row, then you need to get the `NamingContainer` (read: parent) of the button that was clicked, like this:

```
protected void btnAssign(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow theClickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    // Check to make sure the clicked row could be found before using it
    if(theClickedRow != null)
    {
        // Find the amount label control
        Label theAmountLabel = theClickedRow.FindControl("lblAmount") as Label;

        // Again, make sure we actually have something before using it
        if(theAmountLabel != null)
        {
            // Get the actual label's text here
            string theAmountLabelText = theAmountLabel.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Karl, that got me the row but when I try to do something like get the field, for example, var amount = theClickedRow.Cells[0].Text; I get empty text despite the data being rendered.  I like this approach but I guess I am missing something....

Comment: @user2146538 - Use `FindControl()` to get to the server control, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has already been answered, but I figured I'd give an alternate option.

You can always add attributes to server controls, and just pull them later.

For example, I can add the preAuthAmount to the link button as an attribute named "preAuthAmount".

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("preAuthAmount") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Assign+" preAuthAmount='<%# Eval("preAuthAmount") %>' itemID='<%# Eval("itemID") %>' OnClick="btnAssign"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then just pull the attribute in the click event

```
protected void btnAssign(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string preAuthAmount= ((LinkButton)sender).Attributes["preAuthAmount"];
    string itemID= ((LinkButton)sender).Attributes["itemID"];
}
```

It's a lot less code and pretty easy to read.

A third option would be to use datakeys

In the markup of the gridview, add all the fields you want to be able to access to the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTransactionHistory" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
    onselectedindexchanging="gvTransactionHistory_SelectedIndexChanging" 
    DataKeyNames="ID, preAuthAmount, AnyField">
```

These datakeys can be accessed in the code behind with the row index

```
protected void btnAssign(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var rowIndex = (((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
    var id = gvTransactionHistory.DataKeys[rowIndwx].Values["ID"];
    var preAuthAmount = gvTransactionHistory.DataKeys[rowIndwx].Values["preAuthAmount"];
}
```

The issue with the other answer is that it's a bit unstable.  The "findcontrol" method only looks for direct descendants, and may not always work.

Comment: Javalsu, also a good suggestion, however, I want to access more than one field in the row.  I limited my sample question to one item for simplicity.

Comment: There's no limit to the number of attributes you can add.  You can add as many fields as you want.

Comment: I also added a third option. The findcontrol option works, but it's a bit wonky and can cause issues.